# Chrome deletes all my cookies, saved passwords, etc

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Chrome seems to keep deleting my data without asking me. I haven't run CCleaner or anything similar. How can I fix this?

edit: Now using Chromium. Issue persists.

Comment: some browsers have an option which says:
delete browsing history at exit.
check this in your browser's settings.

Comment: This is one of the first things I checked. It's not enabled. Thanks for the reply, though. http://prntscr.com/84uvzc

Comment: I wonder if you're running some kind of cleaning program in the background.  For example Ccleaner has a manual clean that wipes out cookies.  Maybe there's another program that does that automatically.

Comment: Are you perhaps running a private session thinking its a normal session?

Comment: @Ramhound Nope.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't have any other programs other than CCleaner that do this and that feature is disabled.

Comment: @Spectro - I'm sorry, I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

**Adjust cookie permissions**

1. Click the wrench icon on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Settings**.
3. Click *Show advanced settings*.
4. In the "Privacy" section, click the Content settings button.
5. In the "Cookies" section, you can change the following cookies settings:
   Choose "Allow cookies by default". (you may choose the "Keep cookies and site data by default until you quit your browser")

Did you sync your Password?

All you have to do is,

1. Open Google Chrome > Click on Menu Button which is at top right corner
2. Click on Sign in > Just log in to your Google account (skip this step if already signed-in)
3. Now go to Settings (type chrome://settings in address bar aka omnibox) > Under Sign in, select Advance sync settings...
4. Check on Password and hit OK.

Comment: Yes, I've checked these already. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, which points to another thing to check:

> If you want Google Chrome to automatically delete cookies when you close all your browser windows, select the "Keep local data only until I quit my browser" checkbox in the Content Settings dialog. You can also make exceptions so that specific sites’ cookies are deleted whenever you close your browser.

I wonder if that choice is checked in your Chrome.

Comment: This option is unchecked for me.

Comment: Make sure your account hasn't been compromised.  It couldn't hurt to change your password even if you don't see any evidence.  ---  I suppose you already tried uninstalling, removing all traces of chrome from your computer, and starting fresh?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll change my password just to be safe, though.